# How to create a user-defined function in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions, plpgsql

I have the following query in Postgres. I want to have a function where the user can define the value of record_year and record_month using the function call, dynamically without having to specify in the query statement. That way the same query can be reused for different user input values for record_year and record_month (in this case). Can anybody help me out?

```
SELECT x.sid, x.record_year, x.record_month, y.addr
FROM x
FULL OUTER JOIN y
  ON x.sid = y.sid
WHERE x.record_time='23:50' 
  and x.record_year='2020' 
  and x.record_month='1'
group by x.station_id, x.record_year, x.record_month, y.addr;
```

The function call could be something like, `select function_name(record_year, record_month);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are returning a result the function should be defined as `returns table()`. PL/pgSQL is not required if all you want to do is to return a result. A SQL function will be enough.

```
create function get_data(p_time time, p_year int, p_month int)
  returns table (sid int, record_year int, record_month int, addr text)
as
$$
  SELECT x.sid, x.record_year, x.record_month, y.addr
  FROM x
    FULL OUTER JOIN y ON x.sid = y.sid
  WHERE x.record_time p_time
    and x.record_year = p_year
    and x.record_month = p_month
  group by x.station_id, x.record_year, x.record_month, y.addr
$$
language sql
stable;
```

You **have** to adjust the data types of the returned columns - I have only guessed them based on name.

Note that your full outer join is really a `left join` because of the conditions on table `x`

As it is a set returning function, use it like a table in the `FROM` clause:

```
select *
from get_data(time '23:50', 2020, 1);
```

Comment: Heyy, is it possible to pass the name of the tables in the function call? In the example above, x and y are the two tables involved. Suppose i want to user-define the tables upon which i want to perform the query. Is it possible to pass the table names in the function call??? If that's possible could you please show me an example of how to do it?!! Just curious. Thanks alot.